# How to add a custom label to facet_grid()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to add a a custom facet label to a plot that was facetted with `facet_grid()` as follows:

```
p <- qplot(wt, mpg, data = mtcars)
p <- p + facet_grid(. ~ vs, labeller = label_bquote(alpha^a==alpha^b))
```

This still works fine. However, when I add the variable on which I'm splitting to the equation in the facet label, like this:

```
p <- qplot(wt, mpg, data = mtcars)
p <- p + facet_grid(. ~ vs, labeller = label_bquote(alpha^a==alpha^b==.(x)))
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Error: unexpected '==' in "    p <- p + facet_grid(. ~ vs, labeller = label_bquote(alpha^a==alpha^b=="

Could someone help me out on this seemingly trivial problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not that you're adding the variable, it's the second `==` that causes the problem. This is an issue with the way R parses the operators. You can control what R sees with `{}`:

```
p <- p + facet_grid(. ~ vs, labeller = label_bquote({alpha^a==alpha^b}==.(x)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This will work if you just add appropriate brackets.

```
p <- p + facet_grid(. ~ vs, labeller = label_bquote({alpha^a==alpha^b}==.(x)))
```